# copy.deepcopy changes values in python

Tags: python, copy, artificial-intelligence

I am working on an AI project and have found a mysterious bug in the code
this is to do with the deepcopy function in python

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0/(1+np.exp(-x))

import pygame,sys,random,time,copy
from pygame.locals import *

import numpy as np

pygame.init()

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

neuronamount=34
valstrength=5.0

class Neuron(object):
    global neuronamount
    global brain
    global valstrength
    
    def __init__(self,x,a):
        self.a=a
        self.x=x
        self.pos=[random.randint(50,800),random.randint(50,600)]
        self.size=25
        self.numaxons=random.randint(1,int(neuronamount/2))
        #self.numdendrites=random.randint(1,int(neuronamount/2))
        self.axons=[]
        self.dendrites=[]
        self.value=random.random()*2.0-1.0
        
        for x in range(self.numaxons):
            while True:
                num=random.randint(0,neuronamount-1)
                if num!=self.x:  
                    break
                
            self.axons.append([num,random.random()*valstrength-valstrength/2.0])

        """for x in range(self.numdendrites):
            while True:
                num=random.randint(0,neuronamount-1)
                if num!=self.x:  
                    break
                
            self.dendrites.append([num,random.random()*2-1.0])"""

    def eval(self):
        val=0.0

        for x in range(len(self.axons)):
            val+=brains[self.a].neurons[self.axons[x][0]].value*self.axons[x][1]

        self.value=sigmoid(val)*2.0-1.0

class NeuralNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self,inputnum,hiddennum,outputnum,x):
        self.inputnum=inputnum
        self.hiddennum=hiddennum
        self.outputnum=outputnum
        self.neurons=[]
        self.x=x

        i=0

        for x in range(inputnum):
            self.neurons.append(Neuron(i,self.x))
            i+=1

        for y in range(hiddennum):
            self.neurons.append(Neuron(i,self.x))
            i+=1

        for z in range(outputnum):
            self.neurons.append(Neuron(i,self.x))
            i+=1

    def run(self):
        for x in range(len(self.neurons)):
            self.neurons[x].eval()

        myList=[]

        for x in range(self.outputnum):
            myList.append(self.neurons[self.inputnum+self.hiddennum+x].value)

        return myList
            
brains=[]

germs=[]

"""for x in range(neuronamount):
    neurons.append(Neuron(x))"""

for x in range(20):
    brains.append(NeuralNetwork(2,30,2,x))
    germs.append([100,100])

def tweakbrain(brain):
    global neuronamount
    
    newbrain=brain

    numchanges=10 ##cant be too high
    evolutionchangefactor=1.0*valstrength
    chanceofdeletion=20
    chanceofaddition=20

    for x in range(numchanges):
        if random.randint(0,chanceofdeletion)==1:
            val=random.randint(0,len(newbrain.neurons)-1)
            if newbrain.neurons[val].numaxons>1:
                #val2=random.randint(0,len(newbrain.neurons[random.randint(0,newbrain.neurons-1)
                del newbrain.neurons[val].axons[random.randint(0,newbrain.neurons[val].numaxons-1)]
                newbrain.neurons[val].numaxons-=1
                continue

        elif random.randint(0,chanceofaddition)==1:
            val=random.randint(0,len(newbrain.neurons)-1)
            
            while True:
                num=random.randint(0,neuronamount-1)
                if num!=newbrain.neurons[val].x:  
                    break
                
            newbrain.neurons[val].axons.append([num,random.random()*valstrength-valstrength/2.0])
            newbrain.neurons[val].numaxons+=1

            continue

        else:
            val2=random.randint(0,len(newbrain.neurons)-1)
            val=random.randint(0,newbrain.neurons[val2].numaxons-1)
            newbrain.neurons[val2].axons[val][1]+=random.random()*evolutionchangefactor

            if newbrain.neurons[val2].axons[val][1]>1:
                newbrain.neurons[val2].axons[val][1]=1

            elif newbrain.neurons[val2].axons[val][1]<0:
                newbrain.neurons[val2].axons[val][1]=0.0

            continue

    return newbrain

def perform(brain):
    germpos=[100,100]

    for x in range(500):  
        brain.neurons[0].value=1.0
        brain.neurons[1].value=1.0
            
        vector=brain.run()

        germpos[0]+=vector[0]
        germpos[1]+=vector[1]

    return 800-germpos[0]
            
def evolve(brains):
    topbrain=brains[0]

    val=perform(topbrain)

    print(val)
    
    for x in range(100):
        mybrains=[]

        for i in range(20):
            mybrains.append(topbrain)
        
        for y in range(len(brains)):
            mybrains[y]=tweakbrain(mybrains[y])

            val2=perform(mybrains[y])

            #print(val)

            if val<210:
                break

            if val2<val:
                print(val2)
                topbrain=mybrains[y]
                val=val2

    return mybrains

#brains=evolve(brains)

brains2=copy.deepcopy(brains)

germs2=[]
for x in range(20):
    germs2.append([200,200])

while True:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.draw.circle(screen,(0,255,0),(300,100),10)

    for x in range(len(brains)):
        brains2[x].neurons[0].value=1.0
        brains2[x].neurons[1].value=1.0
        
        vector=brains2[x].run()

        germs[x][0]+=vector[0]
        germs[x][1]+=vector[1]

        pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,0,0),germs[x],10)
            
    #neurons[1].value=1.0

    #time.sleep(0.5)

    pygame.display.update()
```

I find this code releases the blobs in a single vector

however if I remove the copy.deepcopy

```
    for x in range(len(brains)):
       brains[x].neurons[0].value=1.0
       brains[x].neurons[1].value=1.0

       vector=brains[x].run()

       germs[x][0]+=vector[0]
       germs[x][1]+=vector[1]
```

the blobs stay in the centre of the screen playing with each other now this means copy.deepcopy isn't doing an exact clone of the class which is difficult for me to understand I want the blobs that fluctuate between positions instead of giving out a single vector so I could theoretically train my blobs to move around corners to goals instead of being stuck in one single vector

Comment: `brains` is a list of `NeuralNetwork` instances... but copy/deepcopy don't know how to copy objects unless the class defines `__deepcopy__` method https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html, so currently you get a new list containing the same instances

Comment: can you post an example of the deepcopy function in the class im a bit confused

Comment: even using the deepcopy function it is still releasing the wrong circles

Comment: I don't know if this is the actual problem as there's a lot of code in your question (try creating a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but if you think behaviour is wrong because `brains2=copy.deepcopy(brains)` did not give you copies then defining a `__deepcopy__` method on the class should allow deepcopy to work

Comment: eg `def __deepcopy__(self): return NeuralNetwork(self.inputnum, self.hiddennum, self.outputnum, self.x)` would be a minimal implementation, although that won't preserve current state of any neurons

Comment: yeah that doesn't work for me as I need the original state of the neurons to remain and they keep giving out the rigid vectors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246618/discussion-between-user2592835-and-anentropic).